# Merging two vertical blocks with vim

Tags: gvim, merge

I have 2 files

file1.txt
a =
b =

file2.txt
1
2

Can I merge them using gvim so that the output looks like :
a = 1
b = 2

Comment: There is a similar question (2 blocks from the same file) on SO: [Merge multiple lines (two blocks) in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10760326/298479)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yank a vertical block: Select e.g. the lines in `file2.txt` with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, yank with <kbd>y</kbd> and paste after moving to end of the first line in `file1.txt` with <kbd>p</kbd>.

If you run `vim` on a GNU stack you could also use the `paste` program to do the same. Use `-d` to specify what delimiter to use between the fields from the files.

```
paste -d "" 1 2 > merged.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

if you're working on Unix or Linux, just use the paste command:

:%!paste - file2.txt

this also works in the classic vi, or direct from the command line:

$ paste file1.txt file2.txt >out.txt

Hope, this helps

Answer (score 1):

works with pure vim as well:

```
 % vim -O file1.txt file2.txt  # open both files vertically splitted
```

then in file1.txt yank the block to a named register, lets say 'a':

- <kbd>gg</kbd> go to begin of file
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> go to select block mode
- <kbd>G</kbd> go to last line
- <kbd>$</kbd> go to last character on last line
- <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> yank to register 'a'

then switch over to file2.txt and do a:

- <kbd>gg</kbd> go to begin of file
- <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> paste content of register 'a' before text

Answer (score 0):

Also could you on Linux use the command :read for paste text of one file to other file, for example:

Both case, first open a file with vim, after you positions in a section of the file and execute:

> :read file1.txt

or

> : read! cat file1.txt

It´s very useful for join content of two or more files...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Your answer is about cut/paste, while the question is very clearly about merging. Please read the questions carefully and avoid posting unrelated information.